# Недостижимый код в Java

Tags: java

> **Недостижимый код** в `Java` считается ошибкой.

Что значит недостижимый код?

Comment: Код, который не может выполниться ни при каких условиях, что возможно вычислить на этапе компиляции. Например, в `return 3; int x = 2` последнее выражение будет недостижимо

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Тот, в который программа никогда не зайдёт, и который приводит к ошибке времени компиляции. Например:

```
public int method() {
    int i = 1;
    return i;
    i++; // последняя команда никогда не выполнится, 
         // компилятор выведет сообщение об ошибке; 
         // это недостижимый код
}
```

И следующий код также является недостижимым (также приведёт к ошибке времени компиляции):

```
while (false) { x=3; }
```

И вот другой пример:

```
public static final CONST = 1;

if (CONST == 1) {
    //Этот код будет выполняться всегда 
} else {
    //Этот код никогда не выполнится 
}
```

Код в блоке `else` никогда не выполнится, но в техническом смысле этот код не является "недостижимым", так как ошибки времени компиляции не произойдёт.

Подробнее смотрите [тут](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.21).

Comment: Первый пример не является примером недостижимого кода т.к. он не приводит к compile-time ошибке - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.21

Comment: @temq, спасибо, действительно, мой ответ был не совсем верным, исправила!

Answer (score 3):

Это код, инструкции, которые недостижимы при выполнении. Для получения этой ошибки достаточно написать что-то после ключевого слова `return;`, ибо после него метод завершается.

Пример:

```
void wrongMethod(){
    //some code here
    return;//выходим из метода - дольше ничего не выполнится и компилятор это не пропустит
    System.out.println(); //ошибка компиляции
}
```